# How to get parameter filename of workflows from Informatica Metadata

Tags: metadata, informatica

I need to get details of the parameter file that is used by the workflows. Do we have a metadata query that can provide such information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below can give you the Parameter file used by a session or workflow.  Note that if the Informatica metadata repository is on SQL Server a "cast" is needed as the data type of ATTR_VALUE is TEXT.
Additionally, you can get this from the workflow run log if it is a workflow that is already executed.
Note that a best practice is to define the parameter file location off of a reference to a server side parameter (e.g. $PMRootDir).  So the location may come back as "$PMRootDir\ParamFiles\wf_LOAD_FILES.parm".

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      B.SUBJECT_AREA,
      B.TASK_NAME AS SES_WF_NAME,
      cast(A.ATTR_VALUE as varchar(200)) AS PRM_FILE_PATH
FROM
       [INFA_META].[dbo].OPB_TASK_ATTR A,
       [INFA_META].[dbo].REP_ALL_TASKS B
WHERE
        A.ATTR_ID IN (1,4)
        AND A.TASK_ID = B.TASK_ID
        AND B.task_name like 'wf_%'
ORDER BY 1,2 ASC
```

Comment: That exactly provides me the data